# How to recover permissions on freebsd

Tags: freebsd, ownership

Can not login to system after start server:

> openpam_check_desc_owner_perms() : /etc/pam.d/login insecure perms

Started system in single-user mod. There are all system dirs (/boot , /lib ...)
 nobody:nogroup 
ownership.

Ofc, i cannot just chown system dirs. So, how can i restore ownership to root?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should use a [live boot](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/using-live-cd.html) downloaded from [official repository](http://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/). I don't think rescue mode (in this case) can save you.

In live the live environment, just mount your impacted filesystems somewhere:

```
mount /dev/${your_partition} /mnt
```

Now, you can use [`mtree`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mtree) to set good rights on all default files and directory. This command will re-create your tree with good rights. Before executing it, you can run it to check state of your filesystem.

```
# check before act
mtree -f /etc/mtree/BSD.root.dist -p /mnt 
# you can now apply change
mtree -u -f /etc/mtree/BSD.root.dist -p /mnt
```

You can find more mtree files in /etc/mtree:

- `BSD.debug.dist`
- `BSD.include.dist`
- `BSD.sendmail.dist`
- `BSD.usr.dist`
- `BSD.var.dist`

After doing that, you can now run [`mergemaster`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mergemaster). `mergemaster` will warn when some files aren't well configured with good rights:

```
mergemaster -iD /mnt
```

If you have still issue, you can download or fetch FreeBSD source from [SVN](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/svn.html), extract them, and reinstall your configuration files manually (do a backup of your configuration before doing that and please read official [FreeBSD documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/makeworld.html) about using source).

```
cd /usr/src
svnlite https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/releng/${your_freebsd_release} .
cd /usr/src/etc
make install DESTDIR=/mnt
```

You can now reboot your computer or server  without live CD.

Comment: the `-U` option for `mtree` is a tiny tad more applicable in this case :)

"Same as -u except that a mismatch is not considered to be an error if it was corrected."